# PHP database SQL insert

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I am trying to write data form mine app to a external database. 
I just get no response form my PHP page. When I look at the variables that I send to the PHP page, they are received good and nothing goes wrong at that moment. 
But when I do an INSERT with SQL it goes wrong. (I think). 
When I go to mine PHPadmin page and I do next SQL command, it works:

```
INSERT INTO images (FBid,Datum,Lat,Longi,Image) 
VALUES ('1846465164',
'2016-08-25 14:14:15',10.5,5.69,'/9j/
 4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wBDAAEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQE
 BAQEBQBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQH/2wBDAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEB')
```

So i have next database;

```
ID(PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT), 
FBid (varchar(255)), 
Datum (datetime), 
Lat (Double), 
Longi(Double), 
Image(Blob).
```

And this is my php page:

```
<?php



 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

   define('HOST','localhost');
 define('USER','XXXXXXXXX');
 define('PASS','XXXXXXXXX');
 define('DB','database2');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

 $image = $_POST['image'];
 $FBid = $_POST['FBid'];
 $date = $_POST['Date'];
 $long = $_POST['long'];
 $lat = $_POST['lat'];

 $stmt = $con->prepare(
                "INSERT INTO images (FBid,Datum,Lat,Longi,Image) 
                 VALUES (:Fbid,:date,:lat,:long,:image)"); 
        $stmt->bindParam(":Fbid",$FBid);
        $stmt->bindParam(":date", $date);
        $stmt->bindParam(":lat", $lat);
        $stmt->bindParam(":long", $long);
        $stmt->bindParam(":image","s",$image);
        $stmt->execute();

$check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

 if($check == 1){
 echo "Image Uploaded Successfully";
 }else{
 echo "Error Uploading Image";
 }
 mysqli_close($con);
 }else{
 echo "Error";
 }
```

Thank you guys!

Regards,
Stijn

Comment: That looks like PDO code, not `mysqli`. Are you sure that's correct? Also there's no need to create intermediate variables like `$FBid` if they're only used once. Just put the `$_POST` data directly in the `bindParam` call.

Comment: You shouldn't have the "s" in the image parameter binding

Comment: @tadman I deleted the 'mysqli' but no difference. What is the problem with creating variabbles?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes I deleted the "s" still no difference.

Comment: If you want to use named placeholders, which is a good idea, use PDO. `mysqli` doesn't support them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the database connection, you are using [mysqli prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) wrongly. In the INSERT statement, it looks like a PDO version. If you want to use PDO version, have a look at this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php). You can't mix PDO and mysqli. The procedural style for mysqli_prepare is like below:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
if ( !$stmt ) {
   die('mysqli error: '.mysqli_error($con);
}
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssddb', $FBid,$date,$lat,$long,$image);
if ( !mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
   die( 'stmt error: '.mysqli_stmt_error($stmt) );
}

$check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
if($check == 1){
 echo 'Image successfully uploaded';
}else{
 echo 'Error uploading image';
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still don't work. 

I changed it to what you said.

When i add an echo before the bind_param, is get the echo,. I place is behind the bind_param, I don't get the echo.

I think something goes wrong there. 

I also did again an echo of al mine variables and they look like this:
$FBid = 15325244
$date = 2015-08-25 14:14:14
$lat = 100.02
$long = 100.6
$image = /9j/......

So there is no problem I think.

Comment: I updated my answer. Added mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

Comment: No change. I placed the first if in comment, to check if there where any errors when I open the page in my browser.
When I open it in my browser, i get this warning:
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, boolean given in /home/jail/home/sbosmans2/public_html/Android_app_server/upload.php on line 18

Comment: Have you tried exactly with the updated version of my answer?

Comment: Yes, I literally copy paste your code.
define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','xx');
define('PASS','xx');
define('DB','database2'); 
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');
$image = $_POST['image'];
$FBid = $_POST['FBid'];
$date = $_POST['Date'];
$long = $_POST['long'];
$lat = $_POST['lat'];  
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO images VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssddb', $FBid,$date,$lat,$long,$image);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
$check = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

Comment: I found the solution! Because in my table there is an auto-increment colum. I needed to add a 'null' value.
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO images VALUES (null,?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

Thank you! :)